# How to Sinch intigration in xamarin.form?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I already integrated **sinch** on android studio but I want to  use in **xamarin.forms** for all cross platform applications such as (android,ios,windows phone)

I want  Sinch WebRtc https://www.sinch.com intigration in xamarin forms.

Comment: how to sinh webrtc sdk impliment on xamrin.form

Comment: I am looking for the solution too, we are developing shopping app using XF in visual studio 2017, we like to implement VoIP call, guide me